# Programmatically add a site to Manage Exception for all browser to Allow Pop-up Blocker

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

The users of my website are facing a problem to manually add site to exception to allow pop up. So I wanted to know if it possible to add a specific site to exception through code so that the browser opens pop up only for that site even if the settings say block pop up.
I.e. I need to register a site to exception to allow popup programmatically.

My code is simple. It uses window.open("abc.aspx") on window.load

Comment: That would defeat the point in choosing to block popups.

Comment: Maybe don't use popups? When I come across a website the tried to pop up a window, I immediately close it and never go back.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. However, pop is necessary in my case as it show some imp information to the user. We have developed this site and users all over the globe are using it. We can't easily make code changes.
Although, I went through some website eg. Citibank. When you click on login button, a new window pop up opens. So how is that possible?